# Child theme works in local environment but is not working on remote

Tags: child-theme, customization, staging

I'm working on a child theme of "colormag" theme. It works in developmet but not when I deploy it to staging.

It means that changes I made in the child theme are rendered in local but are not rendered in remote.

**UPDATE**: It is a Trellis/Bedrock project. I think the issue is related to WP, not to Trellis. To see the entire theme and child theme in context:
https://github.com/aitormendez/obrunete/tree/master/web/app/themes

This is the header of my `colormag-child/style.css` file:

```
/*
 Theme Name: ColorMag child
 Author: Aitor
 Template: colormag
 Version:      1.0.0
 Text Domain:  colormag-child
*/
```

This is the header of style.css original colormag theme (I don't know whether is relevant):

```
/*
Theme Name: ColorMag
Theme URI: http://themegrill.com/themes/colormag/
Author: ThemeGrill
Author URI: http://themegrill.com
Description: ColorMag is a perfect responsive magazine style WordPress theme. Suitable for news, newspaper, magazine, publishing, business and any kind of sites. Get free support at http://themegrill.com/support-forum/ and check the demo at http://demo.themegrill.com/colormag/
Version: 1.1.5
License: GNU General Public License, version 3 (GPLv3)
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt
Tags: one-column, two-columns, right-sidebar, left-sidebar, flexible-header, custom-header, custom-background, custom-menu, custom-colors, sticky-post, threaded-comments, translation-ready, featured-images, theme-options, post-formats, footer-widgets, blog, e-commerce, news
Text Domain: colormag

Resetting and rebuilding styles have been helped along thanks to the fine work of
Eric Meyer http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html
along with Nicolas Gallagher and Jonathan Neal http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/
and Blueprint http://www.blueprintcss.org/
*/
```

- Is there something wrong in the child theme header?
- If yes, why is it
  working on local?
- If not, Why is not it working on remote?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is not working? Is WordPress up and running? Does it work when you activate a stock theme (twentysixteen)? Have you looked at the server's error logs?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. WP works perfectly. Don't work means that changes made in the child theme are not renderer in remote. I go to update the question whith this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say, but the problem was that, in production, I had activated the parent theme instead of child theme. I am embarrassed by this cluelessness and I apologize for making you waste your time